# HttpWebRequest POST and retrieve data from php script after login

Tags: php, httpwebrequest

Hello guys i am newbie to this stuff so i'll try to explain my problem.I am building application that retrieve data after login to php script that looks like this:

https://zamger.etf.unsa.ba/getrssid.php

(see the page source for php scirpt definition)

and definition(source) here:

Korisničko ime (UID):
        Šifra:

After i login it shows me data that i must collect like this:

RSSID: 1321B312 (this is only data that it shows and nothing else)

I must do this with httpwebrequest but don't know how i tried to do it with POST(data) but it always give me the defnition of php script as response.But i need response to be like "RSSID: 1321B312" not as script definition mentioned above...please heeelp ASAP....

Comment: Show us PHP please, on the page you see only HTML result of php script. Inside php script try to debug the $_POST variable by the <?php var_dump($_POST);?>

Comment: can't see the php i didn't wrote it that is the problem...it is written by another man who sent us just this link to work with :S

Comment: to be straight i am building  windows smart device application that get rss feed with this rssid

Answer (score 0):

Define a form action to begin. So if the same page, *getrssid.php*, will be processing the form, use:

```
<form action="getrssid.php" method="POST">
```

After that, you must code getrssid.php to accept the incoming data via POST. POST data is stored in the PHP variables $_POST['inputname']. So if you have the input name as "login", the value entered will be stored in $_POST['login']. Same thing applies for the password.

So, here's a sample of what a basic POST data handling script should look like. Note that this script does not verify the login credentials, sanitize the inputs, or anything of the sort. It is just to show you how to handle POST DATA.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
  // Form is submitted.
  echo 'RSSID: 1321B312';
} else {
 // Form is not submitted.
 // Display Form.
 echo 'Form HTML here';
}

?>
```

If you are really server conscious, you should put the if ... else statement in the opposite order so the most likely outcome (form not submitted) is evaluated first.

Merry Christmas!

Comment: but i cant define form action because it is not mine script and i can't redefine it...i must use it as it is :(((  Merry christmas too :)))

Comment: but i cant define form action because it is not mine script and i can't redefine it...i must use it as it is :(((  .....or you meant this this i change action with POST data?   Merry christmas too :))) P.s this is mine code

Comment: to be straight i am building  windows smart device application that get rss feed with this rssid